# Is it possible to use the aspect fill content mode combined with the top content mode in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, image

For a `UIImageView`, I am using the aspect fill content mode. It's OK, but for some images, it will cut from the top because I used `clipsToBounds = true`. So here is what I want: I want to make the two filters active at the same time, for example:

Here is an image view that I set to aspect fill:

[image: image view with the aspect fill content mode]

...and an image view I set using `contentMode = .top`:

[image: image view with the top content mode]

So I want to merge these two content modes. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Note** This approach involves literally building a new image, which is extremely non-performant and would only be used in unusual situations. It's trivial to move and scale a UIImageView in a number of different ways.

--

**Update:** device scaling is now properly handled, thanks to [budidino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331080/3151675) for that!

You should resize the image, so that it will have the width of your image view, but by keeping its aspect ratio. After that, set the image view's content mode to `.top` and enable clipping to bounds for it.

The `resizeTopAlignedToFill` function is a modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29534779/3151675).

```
func setImageView() {
    imageView.contentMode = .top
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    let image = <custom image>
    imageView.image = image.resizeTopAlignedToFill(newWidth: imageView.frame.width)
}

extension UIImage {
    func resizeTopAlignedToFill(newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let newHeight = size.height * newWidth / size.width
        
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Comment: The `let scale` here is unused

Comment: This isn't keeping the aspect ratio of the image, the height stays the same and the width is updated so the image is squashed/stretched.

Comment: @JamesP You're right, thanks for the notice, the calculation of `newHeight` was missing. I updated my code.

Comment: This is an incredibly bad idea.  It's horrifically wrong.  You simply do this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38502613/294884

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.size.width / imageView.frame.size.width orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution. First, you set comtentMode to top then you resize image

```
func resize(toWidth scaledToWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let image = self
        let oldWidth = image.size.width
        let scaleFactor = scaledToWidth / oldWidth
        let newHeight = image.size.height * scaleFactor
        let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor
        let scaledSize = CGSize(width:newWidth, height:newHeight)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scaledSize, false, 0)
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scaledSize.width, height: scaledSize.height))
        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return scaledImage!
    }

imageView.contentMode = .top
imageView.image = imageView.resize(toWidth:imageView.frame.width)
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer was scaling down the image and therefore lowering the quality on @2x and @3x devices. This should produce the same result with better image quality:

```
extension UIImage {
  func resizeTopAlignedToFill(containerSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let scaleTarget = containerSize.height / containerSize.width
    let scaleOriginal = size.height / size.width

    if scaleOriginal <= scaleTarget { return self }

    let newHeight = size.width * scaleTarget
    let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width, height: newHeight)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, scale)
    self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
  }
}
```

then to use it just:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "portrait").resizeTopAlignedToFill(containerSize: imageView.frame.size)
```

Comment: I just tested this code and it scales the image incorrectly, so it looks like it's stretched.

Comment: Otherwise, thank you for the info about the incorrect 2x and 3x scaling, I'll update my answer!

Answer (score -1):

as a matter of performance I would suggest to put the UIImageView with the full image size / aspect ratio into a ContainerView with clipsToBounds set to true.

Answer (score -2):

Swift 5:

```
imageView.contentMode = .top
if let image = UIImage(named: "xxx"),
   let cgImage = image.cgImage {
    imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: image.size.width / view.frame.size.width * UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .up)
}
```