# How can I use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill for the top portion

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

If I do `self.imageOfCatalog.Image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;// | UIViewContentModeTop;`

I get what I want with a small cache. Looks like IOS then put the center of the image.

I want the UIImageView to show the top of the image and crop the rest.

How would I do so?

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Image is good enough. However, I want the part being shown to be the top part rather than the center part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not possible with an UIImageView,

- You'll have to subclass UIView
- Add an UIImageview as a property and add it as subview.
- set clipsToBounds to YES  `[self setClipsToBounds:YES];`
- Align the UIImageView to the top of the view
- Resize the UIImageView based on the proportions of the image in layoutSubviews

An example could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272335/alignment-uiimageview-with-aspect-fit).

Comment: Really awesome answer without relying on Core Graphics Framework.

Comment: However, I think there is no need to subclass `UIView`. Just drag a `UIImageView` to a `UIView`, and anchor the imageView's top, left and right sides to the view separately, then `view.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: What a pity, subclassing is needed and much better.