# UIImageView - anyway to use 2 content modes at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So in my scenario, I have a square that is (for understanding's sake) 100x100 and need to display an image that is 300x800 inside of it.

What I want to do is be able to have the image scale just as it would with `UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill` so that the width scales properly to 100.

However, after that, I would like to then "move" the image up to the top of the image instead of it putting it inside the imageView right in the center, basically what `UIViewContentMode.Top` does.  However that doesn't scale it first.

Is there anyway to do this type of behavior with the built in tools?  Anyway to add multiple contentModes?

Comment: [Here's a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272335/alignment-uiimageview-with-aspect-fit) that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I actually ended up just using a helper function that I wrote to scale the image to a size I need then I crop it based on the square rect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had a helper function that I wrote that scaled an image to a specific size passed in, so I just wrote a function that calculated the scaled image that would fit into the smaller square I had similar to the size AspectFill would do, and then I wrote code that would crop it with the rectangle size I needed at (0,0).