# Align Image of UIButton horizontally right in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIButton with size of 200*200 and I have a image with size of 50*50. I want to horizontally align the image inside imageview, so that image occupy a frame of `(150,75,50,50)` . I tried `[button.imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRight]` but this does not work. How can I align image ?

Comment: Basically I want image to be in the right side of imageview, irrespective of imageview's frame.

Comment: try `imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopRight;`

Comment: `button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;` did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a while since February, but I just encountered the same need in the app I am developing.

I solved it using a custom UIImageView which can be easily integrated into your existing code (it's a drop-in replacement of UIImageView).

You can find the class on github, along with an example: https://github.com/reydanro/UIImageViewAligned

Hope this helps you on your project.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without going for a third party

Comment: One solution is to subclass a UIView containing an UIImageView and change its frame according to image size. For example, you can find one version [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272335/alignment-uiimageview-with-aspect-fit].

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can try this...
Set Mode from property.

Answer (score 0):

You can get size of the image so programmatically adjust the frame according to you need. In your case x position+width should the width of the view there you need to keep image.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this scenario something like this,

Take `UIView` of size `200x200`.

Then add imageview of size `50x50` to that view with frame `(150,75,50,50)`.

And set that image to this imageview. so, your outer view have desired blank space and your imageview fully filled by image and it will looks like image view having image set at right side.

hope this will help :)