# Position UIImageView's image at top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I've got a `UIImageView` which has a height greater than its `UIImage`. It is scaling the image to it's width, but since it's height is greater, it is showing the rest of the `UIImageView` as transparent (what you would expect from `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, which is what the `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` is set to)

However, it is making the top and bottom of the `UIImage` transparent, basically, positioning the image in the center of itself. How can I get it to position itself at the top? When I use `UIViewContentModeTop`, it makes the image too large, so that doesn't work for me. I want some sort of way to scale it just as it does with `UIVIewContentModeScaleAspectFill` but tell it to also position the scaled image at the top of itself. Anyone have any ideas on how to do that?

I would also be able to fix the issue by just trimming the `UIImageView`'s height to be equal to what the `UIImage` is once it's been stretched to the boundaries of its superview, but that seems like a more complex solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272335/alignment-uiimageview-with-aspect-fit

Answer (score 0):

try something like,

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed@"yourImageName.jpeg"];

yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[yourImageView setImage:img];
```